# Strange, indescribable color glitching near edges when using viewport shading in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

I am new to this website. I've been having a problem with viewport shading after installing 2.8. I am trying to make a VHS cassette (for no particular reason), but I have a problem that hasn't been addressed yet, from what I know.

The cassette is supposed to look like a regular VHS, of course. But when I enter look dev shading, it ends up looking like something I can't really describe with text.

[image]

It does this strange thing, adding artifacts to the thing, particularly near the edges of the mesh. The artifacts get smaller as I get closer to the mesh. They seem to reset when I move the camera, beginning to grow back when the camera stops.

Hopefully, someone can find out how to help me out here. For now, I'll just continue working on the model. I am using Eevee, and the computer I'm using is a Dell Inspiron 3668. As mentioned before, I am using Blender 2.8.

Comment: First make sure that your hardware fulfills the minimum requirements to run Blender 2.8 (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). If it does, update your graphics driver.

Comment: Seems like @rjg is right; I updated my drivers after messing around and discovering the driver manager, and I'm no longer encountering these artifacts.

Comment: I was having the same problem and changing the 'surface' property of one of my materials seemed to fix it at least temporarily. I honestly don't know if that actually fixed it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Robert Gutzkow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/74827/robert-g%C3%BCtzkow) solved this question in the comments.

> First make sure that your hardware fulfills the minimum requirements to run Blender 2.8 (blender.org/download/requirements). If it does, update your graphics driver. – Robert Gützkow Aug 19 '19 at 7:18

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for me by checking and unchecking *Screen Space Reflections* in *Render Properties*.